# Category ID not being returned

Tags: categories

So, in my template I get what I'm calling parentCategory, and I can output what I need:

```
{% set parentCategory = craft.categories.slug(craft.request.getSegment(2)) %}
{# parentCategory.title and parentCategory.slug output fine #}
```

But shortly after, I'm wanting to get all the descendants of parentCategory, like so:

```
{% set cats = craft.categories.descendantOf(parentCategory.id).find() %}
{# outputs all categories, whether descendants or not #}
```

It seems parentCategory.id is empty:

```
{{ parentCategory.id }}
{# outputs nothing #}
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong here? Why is no ID being returned while title, slug and my custom fields are working fine?

Here's line 1 and 2 from my template:

```
{% if craft.request.getSegment(3) %}
    {% set parentCategory = craft.categories.slug(craft.request.getSegment(2)) %}
```

If I change line 2 to:
{% set parentCategory = craft.categories.slug(craft.request.getSegment(2)).first() %}

I get the following error:

```
Craft\CategoryModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "first".
```

Yet, I can repeat line 2 later in the template and include .first() and not get the error. What go on?

Answer (score 3):

The `craft.categories` tag returns an `ElementCriteriaModel`, so `parentCategory.title` really shouldn't work. Try changing the first line of code to:

```
{% set parentCategory = craft.categories.slug(craft.request.getSegment(2)).first() %}
```

Comment: That's what I've been trying, but then I get the error: Craft\CategoryModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "first".

Have edited my question to show that.

Comment: That is very weird indeed. Are you sure craft.request.getSegment(2) returns a valid slug? Have you tried hardcoding a known slug into the parameter instead?

Comment: Yep. Definitely does.

Comment: @ClivePortman You’ve tried that exact line of code? That definitely should work.

Comment: @BrandonKelly Definitely. I honestly can't add .first() to line 2 of my template, as described above, without the error. I can on the next line, but not if I remove line 2.

Answer (score 0):

If this is coming from a category’s primary URL – so a `category` variable is already defined for you – another way to get that category’s parent is by using the CategoryModel’s [getParent()](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/categorymodel#getParent) function:

```twig
{% set parentCategory = category.getParent() %}
```